# scope variable update but not the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function which builds a list of athletics events and classes. I have to display whether or not an event/class combination is 'official' or not and this is done by collecting a list of official combinations from the backend and setting the value `event.isOfficial=true` if the combination returned matches the combination that is to be displayed.

```
competitionsService.checkIsOfficial(selectedclasses, selectedevents)
  .then(function (data) {
    //Here we are building the class / event list and checking if the event is official or not
    $scope.currentEditItem.classes.forEach(function (cls) {
      cls.events = selectedEvents;
      cls.events.forEach(function (eventtype) {
        eventtype.forEach(function (event) {
        event.isOfficial = false; // By default no class / events combinations are official
        data.forEach(function (item) {
          if (item.idClass == cls.id && item.idEvent == event.id) {
            event.isOfficial = true;
          }
        });

        if ($scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected) {
          $scope.addTag(event, cls.eventtags[event.intType],
          $scope.currentEditItem.events[event.intType], event.intType, "classevents_" + cls.id + "_", false); 
          // Update the event tags
          $scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected = !$scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected;
        }
      });
    });

    $scope.currentEditItem.classesbysex[cls.intSex].push(cls);
  });
});
```

The relevant html looks like this:

```
  <ul class="inline">
    <li ng-repeat="event in cls.events[eventtype.intType]" class="titlecell">
        <div ng-click="setChecked(cls, event, cls.eventtags[eventtype.intType],currentEditItem.events[eventtype.intType],eventtype,'classevents_'+cls.id+'_')"
             class="checkbox-div" name='event{{event.id}}'
             id='classevents_{{cls.id}}_{{event.id}}'>
            <i ng-class="{'icon-ok': currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected}" class="iconpos"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="titlecell" ng-class="{warn:!event.isOfficial}">{{ event.idEvent }}: {{ event.strName }} - {{ event.isOfficial }} </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that even though the event.isOfficial is set to true in the scope (and this has of course been checked in the debugger) it is not updated in the view.

Notes:
The page is loaded before `competitionsService.checkIsOfficial` is called. This goes to the backend and updates the DOM once the promise has been returned. However, the rest of the data from this callback is correctly displayed.

`$scope.$apply()` throws the error that a `$digest is already in progress`.

Three lines above `event.isOfficial = true`, I set `event.isOfficial = false`. This is reflected in the view. The test `{{ event.isOfficial }}` always shows `false`.

I have very little hair left after working on this for a few hours today. ANY ideas as to what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Took a while to get the right data in, but I have a Plunk working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pBoM4BHlx4h7Cw2jEIfG?p=preview

Comment: This looks like a lot more code than the minimum required to replicate the problem. Maybe a `$timeout`ed `$scope.$apply()` would help?

Comment: That's half the battle, I can't replicate the problem elsewhere! The adding the $timeout ed $scope.$apply() at the end of the loop makes no difference. I can't really add one within it!

Comment: For the `$digest is already in progress` error, try wrapping `$scope.$apply()` in `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();`. This basically checks if angular is already in digest phase. However, its not an official method, but just a workaround.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to the problem, but the `selectedevents` on the first line does not match the `selectedEvents` on the fifth line, as that one has a capital E in the middle.

Comment: poor choice of variable names but yes it's supposed to be like that.

Comment: if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply(); Didn't help, but thanks.

Comment: When you do `cls.events = selectedEvents;` to assign the list of events to each class, do you expect the events to be identical or independent copies? (Because it's the former, and that's what causes problems.)

Comment: They should be independent copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best as I can tell the trouble is that you were changing the `isOfficial` flag on the same events repeatedly, instead of acting on independent copies. This can be remedied easily by applying `angular.copy()` in the right place.

As added bonus I removed a nested loop, by replacing it with a simple map.

In the plunker there seems to be a function missing on the `$scope` object, so I commented it out.

```
competitionsService.checkIsOfficial(selectedclasses, selectedevents)
    .then(function (data) {
        /// prevent a nested forEach-loop by using a map.
        var map = {};
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            map[ [item.idClass,item.idEvent] ] = true;
        });

        //Here we are building the class / event list and checking if the event is official or not
        $scope.currentEditItem.classes.forEach(function (cls) {

            /// make a deep copy so the event-objects are independant.
            cls.events = angular.copy(selectedEvents);

            cls.events.forEach(function (eventtype) {
                eventtype.forEach(function (event) {
                    event.isOfficial = map[ [cls.id, event.id] ] !== undefined;

                    if ($scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected) {
                        /// !! $scope.addTag does not exist in the plunker example.
                        /// $scope.addTag(event, cls.eventtags[event.intType], $scope.currentEditItem.events[event.intType], event.intType, "classevents_" + cls.id + "_", false); 

                        // Update the event tags
                        $scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected = !$scope.currentEditItem.classevent[cls.id][event.id].selected;
                    }
                });
            });

            $scope.currentEditItem.classesbysex[cls.intSex].push(cls);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks towr! That's brilliant, it works perfectly. And also thanks for the map bonus - I will be reviewing some other parts of my code where I can use the same idea.